# Apache rewrite condition for a exact URL match and rewrite rule to absolute URL with no appends

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile/acct
RewriteRule ^/* http://webtest.bca.com/my-account/viewMyBill.html? [R]
```

The above is working for requests containing the `/mobile/acct` in the request uri, but they are also matching other conditions I have where I have two or more conditions and then redirect.

I am looking to modify above to look for a exact match, `^URI$` does not work, starting the URI with ^ and ending it with $ does not work for "exact match" and its redirecting all my other conditions to the same viewMyBill.html where as my other conditions do have /mobile/acct in the URL but they also have other conditions to be met and rewrite to a unique url.

Please help, I have been plucking out my hair in trying to figure out "Exact Match" URL and redirect to a "absolute URL" with no other additional appends.

Thank You in advance!!
Siddh

Comment: *RewriteEngine on                                                                           *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile/acct
*RewriteRule ^/* http://webtest.bca.com/my-account/viewMyBill.html? [R]

Answer (score 0):

See [`RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for patterns

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>   - ...
>   - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which *never* has a leading slash. **Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.**

This means to match an exact path, start *without* slash.

Also add an [`L`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag as recommended in [`R|redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)

> You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but **then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset**, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings.

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/acct$ http://webtest.bca.com/my-account/viewMyBill.html? [R,L]
```

If the substitution is on the same domain, you don't need to repeat the scheme and host.

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/acct$ /my-account/viewMyBill.html? [R,L]
```